# using the response of one test step in another test step request

Tags: json, soapui

How can I use the response of one teststep of a testcase in a teststep of another testcase in SOAP UI test runner? I am using post method and have json body. the response also is json. I want to use a field value which I receive in one test step, in the next test step. Is it possible, If yes, how?

Comment: Did you even try to look at the documentation?!?! http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Usually, each test should be independent.

But here you appear to bring the dependency between the tests.

Anyway, In the first test case, extract the value from the response and add it to the properties of either the same test case or at the test suite level. Then access this value from the next test case.

**Test suite level property**

Set value in first test case -
 `context.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME', 'PROPERTY_VALUE')`

Accessing the above in second test case using *groovy step* - `context.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue('PROPERTY_NAME')`

Accessing the above in the second test case using *request step* -
`${#TestSuite#PROPERTY_NAME}`

Comment: Is this applicable only for string values? Can I not set hashmaps or a json content received in the response to be used in another requests? I tried but failed

Comment: Properties only deals with String type.  May be store entire response as String value and resuse where it is needed.